# How to put [] in my regex

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex that accept almost all valid character 
i have made this regex

```
 "([a-zA-Z0-9]|[- @\\.#&!,:+_?*=/'\"()<>%\"])*$"
```

I want [] square brackets in that regex how can i place it?

Comment: you have to escape the special character `[` with a backwards slash, so `\[`. I also suggest you use https://regex101.com/ or other services, which visualize what the regex truly is

Comment: Use double backslashes to escape special regex metacharacters inside a Java string literal. That also means you need to use ``\\\\``, not ``\\``, to match a literal backslash. And there is no way to put unescaped `]` and `[` inside a character class in a Java regex because they are used to form character class unions/subtractions.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew using double backslashes worked for me \\\[ \\\]